# Join two dictionaries React Hocks useEffect useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

I would like to create a cumulative useState of get's requests that return a dictionary of type {[]}, but without the first blanc space.

In this case, I want to save all the [{}] received from useEffect fetch, inside the const alarms, using useState.

```
const [alarms, setAlarms] = useState([{}])

useEffect(() => {

  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    fetch(`${urlAlarm}/iot1`).then(
      res => res.json()
    ).then(
      body => {
        let merged
        alarms.length === 1 ? merged = body : merged = [...alarms, ...body]
        setAlarms(merged)
      }
    )
  }, 2000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: 1.What the question is?
2.What does "first blanc space" mean?
3.Why did you wrap fetch in setTimeout?